# MapView snaps back to original location - help!

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, android-mapview

I have a mapView with custom annotations and just ran into a problem on a beta tester's iPhone. The mapView won't let the user move to any location.. as soon as you try to move, it snaps right back to the original coordinates.

Any idea why? It doesn't happen in the simulator, and I notice it a little bit on my own device... but it is a consistent problem on another device.

Thanks so much!

```
static BOOL haveAlreadyReceivedCoordinates = NO;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation  {
    if(haveAlreadyReceivedCoordinates) {
    return;
    }

    haveAlreadyReceivedCoordinates = YES;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:loc];
}
```

Comment: I had that once. Check your delegate methods. I assume, somewhere in didUpdateToLocation you are telling him to go back.... otherwhise, post some code....

Comment: Hi Icky... I've updated my question to include my code. Should I just include a stopUpdatingLocation once I'm finished to avoid the constant moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icky put you on the right track. You shouldn't be constantly resetting the map's center to whatever you get back from the location manager. The location manager will send you all sorts of updates.

You may wish to only use the update once and then ignore future updates (by setting some kind of flag), or you may wish to center the map on the user's location only when the user presses a button. In the latter case the only thing you need to do in `didUpdateToLocation:` is store the new location into some member variable.

The reason you don't see this in the simulator is that the location hardware simulator isn't constantly updating the way the real one is.

Comment: Thanks nss! That makes much more sense.. my question now is: Why would my map keep using the new location? Or, how can I make my map use it only once?

Comment: Well, the map is using the new location because you told it to in `didUpdateToLocation`. What you can do is keep a boolean member variable (say `mapLocationUpdated`), which is initially false. In `didUpdateToLocation` you should call `[mapView setCenterCoordinate:loc] only if `mapLocationUpdated` is `false`. After calling that, then set `mapLocationUpdated` to `true`. Alternatively, you could just tell the location manager to stop updating location in `didUpdateToLocation` after you've dealt with it once.

Comment: Thanks nss! I'm quite attracted to using the boolean value option. How would I tell `didUpdateToLocation` to only update if it is false?

Comment: I just updated my question with the boolean value option. It works great when I visit the map tab first.. but on revisit, the location does not work.. how can I fix this?

Comment: All fixed... I added the boolean value in `viewWillAppear` ... Thanks nss!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. I'm glad you got it working. Yes, you may wish to to reset the boolean to false in `viewWillAppear`. One final piece of advice is to make `haveAlreadyReceivedCoordinates` a member variable of your class rather than a static global. This way you can handle having two instances of the class without them interfering.